Animation problems with Flowbite and PrimeNG in Angular 18
I'm developing an Angular 18 zoneless app with Flowbite as primary component library but I had to install PrimeNG too because I needed the <p-multiSelect> for my form.
The thing is, when I added the required "BrowserAnimationsModule" in my "app.config.ts" (without it the dropdown of the p-multiSelect doesn't work), the Flowbite drawer and dropdown that I'm using in my navbar component stopped working.
They only work if I refresh the page, but when I navigate between components, they stop working.
Code of app.component.ts
import { Component, inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  // Dependencias
  private _translateService = inject(TranslateService);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Comprobamos si hay algún idioma almacenado, y si no lo hay, establece el español ('es') por defecto.
    const defaultLang = localStorage.getItem('language') || 'es';
    this._translateService.setDefaultLang(defaultLang);
    this._translateService.use(defaultLang);
  }
}

Code of app.config.ts:
import {
  ApplicationConfig,
  importProvidersFrom,
  provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection,
} from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { HttpClient, provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

// Función que se encarga de cargar los archivos de traducción. (ngx-translate)
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './i18n/', '.json');
}

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection(),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(),
    importProvidersFrom(
      TranslateModule.forRoot({ // ngx-translate
        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
          deps: [HttpClient],
        },
      }),
      BrowserAnimationsModule // PrimeNG
    ),
  ],
};

Code of navbar.component.ts:
import { Component, inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { initDrawers, initDropdowns } from 'flowbite';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [TranslateModule],
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrl: './navbar.component.scss',
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  // Dependencias
  private _sanitizer = inject(DomSanitizer); // Nos permite renderizar SVGs desde TypeScript.

  // Botones del menú desplegable lateral.
  menuItems = [...
  ];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    initDrawers(); // Inicializar menú navbar.
    initDropdowns(); // Inicializar dropdown usuario.
  }
}

Code of search-products.component.ts (the only component where I use the p-multiSelect)
import { Component, inject, OnInit, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { NavbarComponent } from '../../../../shared/layout/navbar/navbar.component';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { InfiniteScrollDirective } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';
import { LoadingOverlayComponent } from '../../../../shared/layout/loading-overlay/loading-overlay.component';
import { ProductsService } from '../../services/products.service';
import { MultiSelectModule } from 'primeng/multiselect';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-products',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    NavbarComponent,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    TranslateModule,
    InfiniteScrollDirective,
    LoadingOverlayComponent,
    MultiSelectModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './search-products.component.html',
  styleUrl: './search-products.component.scss'
})
export class SearchProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  materials: any[] = [];  
  
  searchProductsForm!: FormGroup; // Formulario de búsqueda de productos.
  productList = signal<any[]>([]); // Array que almacenará todos los productos que recojamos del endpoint.
  sortOrder: boolean = true; // true = asc | false = desc
  page = 1; // Posición desde la que empezaremos a recoger datos.
  pageSize = 10; // Número de registros por tanda que recogeremos.
  loading = signal(false); // Signal que controla la pantalla de carga.
  isFormValid = signal(false); // Signal que controla si el formulario es válido para la búsqueda.

  // Dependencias
  private _form = inject(FormBuilder);
  private _productsService = inject(ProductsService);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Inicialización del formulario de búsqueda.
    this.searchProductsForm = this._form.group({
      productRef: [''],
      catalogRef: [''],
      stockFilter:[''],
      productType:['joyas'],
      selectedMaterials:['']
    });

    this.materials = [
      {name: 'Oro'},
      {name: 'Plata'},
      {name: 'Platino'},
  ];
  }

Why is this happening? It's because how Flowbite and PrimeNG manage their animations? I can't have them to work simultaneously, I have to delete the "BrowserAnimationsModule" of my "app.config.ts" for the drawer and dropdown of my navbar to work and I have to include it to the "p-multiSelect" to work (but then the drawer/dropdown stop working).
Thanks for your help and time.

When you import BrowserAnimationsModule into your app, it changes how the framework handles rendering and animations, which can interfere with CSS-only animations like those in Flowbite (which uses Tailwind CSS).
Here are a few things you can try to resolve it:

Use NoopAnimationsModule in specific components or modules that don’t need Angular animations. This will allow Flowbite to function correctly in those contexts.
Separate Angular and Flowbite animations: keep Angular animations only for elements or components that specifically need them, and use Flowbite for others.
To do this, remove BrowserAnimationsModule from your main configuration file, so Angular won’t handle all animations across the app.

I hope it help you!
